# Sorting a data stream before writing to file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, sorting, bigdata

I have an input file which may potentially contain upto 1M records and each record would look like this

`field 1    field 2    field3 \n`

I want to read this input file and sort it based on `field3` before writing it to another file.

here is what I have so far

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    readline = require('readline'),
    stream = require('stream');

var start = Date.now();

var outstream = new stream;
outstream.readable = true;
outstream.writable = true;

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('cross.txt'),
    output: outstream,
    terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    //var tmp = line.split("\t").reverse().join('\t') + '\n';
    //fs.appendFileSync("op_rev.txt", tmp );
    // this logic to reverse and then sort is too slow
});

rl.on('close', function() {
    var closetime = Date.now();
    console.log('Read entirefile. ', (closetime - start)/1000, ' secs');
});
```

I am basically stuck at this point, all I have is the ability to read from one file and write to another, is there a way to efficiently sort this data before writing it

Comment: i am guessing you have already ruled out the possiblity of loading all the data into memory to perform in memory sort, correct?

Comment: I just did a quick test, having javascript perform array.sort on 1M reverse ordered numbers took 6.4 seconds. Test ran on my crappy laptop.

Comment: You could write/use a native extension a la https://ivanvergiliev.github.io/node-cpp/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`DB` and `sort-stream` are fine solutions, *but* DB might be an overkill and I think `sort-stream` eventually just sorts the entire file in an in-memory array (on `through` end callback), so I think performance will be roughly the same, comparing to the original solution.
<del>(but I haven't ran any benchmarks, so I might be wrong).</del>

So, just for the hack of it, I'll throw in another solution :)

---

**EDIT:** 
I was curious to see how big a difference this will be, so I ran some benchmarks.

Results were surprising even to me, turns out **`sort -k3,3` solution is better by far, x10 times faster** then the original solution (a simple array sort), while **`nedb` and `sort-stream` solutions are at least x18 times slower** than the original solution (i.e. at least x180 times slower than `sort -k3,3`).

*(See benchmark results below)*

---

If on a *nix machine (Unix, Linux, Mac, ...) you can simply use
**`sort -k 3,3 yourInputFile > op_rev.txt`** and let the OS do the sorting for you.
You'll probably get better performance, since sorting is done natively.

Or, if you want to process the sorted output in Node:

```
var util = require('util'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    sort = spawn('sort', ['-k3,3', './test.tsv']);

sort.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    // process data
    data.toString()
        .split('\n')
        .map(line => line.split("\t"))
        .forEach(record => console.info(`Record: ${record}`));
});

sort.on('exit', function (code) {
    if (code) {
        // handle error
    }

    console.log('Done');
});

// optional
sort.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    // handle error...
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
```

Hope this helps :)

---

**EDIT:** Adding some benchmark details.

I was curious to see how big a difference this will be, so I ran some benchmarks.

Here are the results (running on a MacBook Pro):

- **[sort1](https://gist.github.com/yoava/fd291e13ef703a4ea68a33c463dc376a)** uses a straightforward approach, sorting the records in an `in-memory array`.
  Avg time: **35.6s** (baseline)
- **[sort2](https://gist.github.com/yoava/7d45c531cf727247c393d43d6033a938)** uses `sort-stream`, as suggested by Joe Krill.
  Avg time: **11.1m** (about **x18.7 times slower**)
  (I wonder why. I didn't dig in.)
- **[sort3](https://gist.github.com/yoava/8a05ad916efb852cfd0f2b3482d7ec0c)** uses `nedb`, as suggested by Tamas Hegedus.
  Time: about **16m** (about **x27 times slower**)
- **[sort4](https://gist.github.com/yoava/78a6f880db73ee4686162caed88a459d)** only sorts by executing `sort -k 3,3 input.txt > out4.txt` in a terminal
  Avg time: **1.2s** (about **x30 times faster**)
- **[sort5](https://gist.github.com/yoava/579fe6953a22ca724ed3afd95929f389)** uses `sort -k3,3`, and process the response sent to stdout  
  Avg time: **3.65s** (about **x9.7 times faster**)

Comment: Interesting results! I think your sort1 link may be pointing at the wrong gist, though, because it's identical to the sort2 implementation. The slowness of sort2 could also be caused by the parser (most likely, IMO) or the transform streams -- impossible to tell from the results here. I would have expected it to be much closer to the in-memory array because that's effectively what sort2 is doing, too.

Comment: Fixed sort1.js link, thanks. Regarding sort2, I was expecting the same thing (and I guess you're right about why).

Answer (score 6):

You can take advantage of streams for something like this. There's a few NPM modules that will be helpful -- first include them by running

```
npm install sort-stream csv-parse stream-transform
```

from the command line.

Then:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sort = require('sort-stream');
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var transform = require('stream-transform');

// Create a readble stream from the input file.
fs.createReadStream('./cross.txt')
  // Use `csv-parse` to parse the input using a tab character (\t) as the 
  // delimiter. This produces a record for each row which is an array of 
  // field values.
  .pipe(parse({
    delimiter: '\t'
  }))
  // Use `sort-stream` to sort the parsed records on the third field. 
  .pipe(sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[2].localeCompare(b[2]);
  }))
  // Use `stream-transform` to transform each record (an array of fields) into 
  // a single tab-delimited string to be output to our destination text file.
  .pipe(transform(function(row) {
    return row.join('\t') + '\r';
  }))
  // And finally, output those strings to our destination file.
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./cross_sorted.txt'));
```

Comment: Running a benchmark, this solution actually turned out much slower than a simple array sort (for 1M rows).

Comment: Note: `sort-stream` appears to simply accumulate all items from the stream into an in-memory array, and then sort it as usual.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options, depending on how much data is being processed. (1M record count with 3 columns doesn't say much about the amount of actual data)

### Load the data in memory, sort in place

```
var lines = [];
rl.on('line', function(line) {
    lines.push(line.split("\t").reverse());
});

rl.on('close', function() {
    lines.sort(function(a, b) { return compare(a[0], b[0]); });

    // write however you want
    fs.writeFileSync(
        fileName,
        lines.map(function(x) { return x.join("\t"); }).join("\n")
    );
    function compare(a, b) {
        if (a < b) return -1;
        if (a > b) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

### Load the data in a persistent database, read ordered

Using a database engine of your choice (for example [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb), a pure javascript db for nodejs)

**EDIT**: It seems that NeDB keeps the whole database in memory, the file is only a persistent copy of the data. We'll have to search for another implementation. [TingoDB](https://github.com/sergeyksv/tingodb) looks promising.

```
// This code is only to give an idea, not tested in any way

var Datastore = require('nedb');
var db = new Datastore({
    filename: 'path/to/temp/datafile',
    autoload: true
});

rl.on('line', function(line) {
    var tmp = line.split("\t").reverse();
    db.insert({
        field0: tmp[0],
        field1: tmp[1],
        field2: tmp[2]
    });
});

rl.on('close', function() {
    var cursor = db.find({})
            .sort({ field0: 1 }); // sort by field0, ascending
    var PAGE_SIZE = 1000;
    paginate(0);
    function paginate(i) {
        cursor.skip(i).take(PAGE_SIZE).exec(function(err, docs) {
            // handle errors

            var tmp = docs.map(function(o) {
                return o.field0 + "\t" + o.field1 + "\t" + o.field2 + "\n";
            });
            fs.appendFileSync("op_rev.txt", tmp.join(""));
            if (docs.length >= PAGE_SIZE) {
                paginate(i + PAGE_SIZE);
            } else {
                // cleanup temp database
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Running a benchmark, this solution actually turned out much slower than a simple array sort (for 1M rows).

Comment: Of course it is, this solution is for the case when your data doesn't fit into memory, as you didn't answer us if you have that much data that cannot be loaded into ram at once.

Answer (score 2):

i had quite similar issue, needed to perform an [external sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

I figured out, after waste a few time on it that i could load up the data on a database and then query out the desired data from it.

It not even matter if the inserts aren't ordered, as long as my query result could be.

Hope it can work for you too.

In order to insert your data on a database, there are plenty of tools on node to perform such task. I have [this pet project](https://github.com/sombriks/microdados-brutos/blob/master/scriptortxt2sql.js) which does a similar job.

I'm also sure that if you [search](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=large%20txt%20data%20import%20node) the subject, you'll find much more info.

Good luck.